# Oracle SQL group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below data in my table,

```
    Id month value

    1  Jun  20
    1  Jul  22
    1  Aug  0
    1  Sep  12
    2  Jun  21
    2  Jul  45
```

I need to group them as

```
Id Jun Jul Aug Sep
1   20  22 0   12
2   21  45
```

I am not sure what syntax i should use. Help appreciated

Comment: serach for pivot table

Comment: Are the months fixed (Jun, Jul, Aug and Sep ONLY)? Also, do you need to identify which months they are (that is, which year they are in)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Gurwinder's answer is workable. Also you can use pivot (in Oracle 11 or above):

```
select *
 from (
  select id, month, value
    from your_table    
)
pivot (
      max(value)
      for month in ('Jun' as "Jun", 'Jul' as "Jul", 'Aug' as "Aug", 'Sep' as "Sep")
)t
```

Comment: @Pat - in both solutions, if your "input" table is already the result of a query where you use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()` or `SUM()`, you can get a simpler result if you combine the "pivoting" (either done manually as in Gurwinder's answer or using the Oracle 11 and above `PIVOT` operation as in Yuriy's answer) with the grouping and counting/summing. Both methods allow you to group, count/sum AND pivot all at once. For more help, if this is your case, show the original query that produces your "inputs".

Comment: What made you use max(value)?

Comment: Whereas pivot requires some aggregate function, it's just a trick make it do its work. In your case you can use sum or another operator as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below:

```
select id,
    sum(decode(month, 'Jun', value)) jun,
    sum(decode(month, 'Jul', value)) jul,
    sum(decode(month, 'Aug', value)) aug,
    sum(decode(month, 'Sep', value)) sep
from my_table group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention the version of Oracle. If you are using Oracle 11g or above, the following example would get you close.

```
create table pivot_test (id number(1), month varchar2(3), value number(2));

insert into pivot_test values (1, 'Jun', 20);
insert into pivot_test values (1, 'Jul', 22);
insert into pivot_test values (1, 'Aug', 0);
insert into pivot_test values (1, 'Sep', 12);
insert into pivot_test values (2, 'Jun', 21);
insert into pivot_test values (2, 'Jul', 45);
commit;

select *
from (select id, month, sum(value) as value from pivot_test group by id, month)
pivot (SUM(value) for (month) in ('Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep'))
order by id
;
```

It yields the following result.

```
        ID      'Jun'      'Jul'      'Aug'      'Sep'
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         20         22          0         12
         2         21         45
```